# Rails helper method that works differently in different environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment, conditional-statements, helper

In a Ruby on Rails application, I have a controller where I'd like some functionality to conditionally run, where the condition is dependent on the environment the application is running in. As a contrived example, in development mode I'd like it to do:

```
if foo == 5:
    ...
end
```

And in production mode, I'd like:

```
if foo > 6:
    ...
end
```

The difference between the two conditions is more complicated than a single constant (5 or 6 in the example above).

What is the most idiomatic way to do this in Rails? Would I write helper methods directly in the `environments/` files? Or add a method to the application controller that checks the current environment? Or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would just add a check for `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` in the logic statements.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-environment-settings

I would change your code to:

```
if foo == 5 && ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "development" then
    ...
elsif foo > 6 && ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "production" then
    ...
end
```

It is just another condition in you flow-control, no need to complicate it.

If you need to do it a lot, a few methods in `application.rb` could help:

```
def isDev
    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "development"
end

def isProd
    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "production"
end
```

Comment: I'm aware of that one (or `Rails.env` in Rails 3 applications). My question is where and how to best incorporate that into the application (in the application controller, in `environment.rb`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I often need to do this in my apps too, in various places. E.g., I don't want to include analytics code in development mode. And so I set up an instance variable or two in the application controller:

```
before_filter :setup_variables

def setup_variables
  @development = (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "development")
  @production  = (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "production")
end
```

I can now test whether I'm in development mode *both* in controllers as well as views.

One other note, though. If you're doing a *lot* of case-based switching (if development / if production), you might want to refactor this into a separate set of objects that you swap out depending on the environment.  E.g., have a DevelopmentLogic lib, and a ProductionLogic lib.